# How to stop my program from running 2 .py simultaneously in QThread

Tags: python, matplotlib, qthread

Im still new in in pyhton. need help with my code that keep running both my code simultaneously.

Each time i press 1 button the program in Qthread will execute both of my matplotlib graf (fifteenGRAF and FourtyGRAF)

---

Here is my main code:

---

```
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.Fourty)
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(FOURTYPSIGRAF.run2)
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Fiften)
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(FIFTEENPSIGRAF.run2)

def Fourty(self):
    self.worker = WorkerThread()
    self.worker.start()

def Fiften(self):
    self.worker2 = WorkerThread2()
    self.worker2.start()

class WorkerThread(QThread):
    def run(self):
      FourtyPSI.run2()

class WorkerThread2(QThread):
    def run(self):
    FifteenPSI.run()
```

---

Here is my fourtyGRAF and FifteenGRAF Code

---

```
def run2():
x_value = 0.0
ser = serial.Serial("COM3", 9600)

ts = time.time()
st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y_%m-%d_%H_%M_%S')
fieldnames = ["x_value", "Timestamp", "PSI"]

with open('data.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csv_writer.writeheader()

while True:
    with open('data.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        cc = str(ser.readline())
        ccc = cc.split("<")
        try:
            ccc = ccc[1].split(">")
            try:
                temphum = float(ccc[0])
                print(temphum)

                if temphum != []:
                    x_value += 1
                    ts = time.time()
                    st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y_%m-%d_%H_%M_%S')
                    # print(temphum)
                    PSI = temphum

                    info = {
                        "x_value": x_value,
                        "Timestamp": st,
                        "PSI": PSI,
                    }

                    csv_writer.writerow(info)
                    print(x_value, PSI)
            except:
                pass
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: could you give us a minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `except: pass` it the worst what you could do. If you get some read error then you will not know it. Better use `except Exception as ex: print(ex)`

Comment: maybe you should use `global running` `running = True` and `while running:` and later you can set `running = False` to stop loop. You could also use it inside code to exit function - `if not running: return` - and this way you can stop thread. Instead normal variable `running` you can use `threading.Event()` or something similar in `QThread`